# NPM Version Not Committing Workspace package.json

Tags: npm, npm-version

When trying to set the version of all work-spaces I have found that only the root workspace change is committed. Steps to reproduce using Angular CLI:

1. `ng new test-workspace --create-application false`
2. `cd test-workspace`
3. `ng generate application test-app`
4. `git add --all`
5. `git commit -m "Application"`
6. `ng generate library test-lib`
7. `git add --all`
8. `git commit -m "Library"`
9. Change root-level `package.json` to include:

   ```json
   "workspaces": [
     "projects/test-lib"
   ]
   ```
10. `git add --all`
11. `git commit -m "Workspaces"`
12. `npm version  --workspaces --include-workspace-root true --workspaces-update false 0.0.2`

After the final step `test-lib/package.json` has been changed to the new version but has not been commited.

Comment: I found the same thing, and wrote https://github.com/textbook/fauxauth/blob/e0beec759973f162ae398f7622ff6d9bab913c4c/bin/version.sh. I think this is because it's built around the idea that different packages in the workspace will change versions at different rates, but you can only have one git tag for a given version, so it doesn't make sense to try to commit and tag those changes.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that makes sense if using anything other than providing an explicit version to `npm version` and to all workspaces?